# How do I schedule a print job in 10.9?

Tags: printing, macos

When printing, I can't seem to find the scheduler in the print dialog box. How do I enable print scheduling in 10.9? I remember in at least 10.5 it being one of the options in the print dialog.

Comment: Would an Apple Script help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Print Job scheduling was removed in OS X 10.7 Lion.** As a workaround, you can pause the printer, print what you want then continue the printer.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this on the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a application called [handyPrint](http://www.netputing.com/applications/handyprint-v5/).

I recommend it since it will also activate the AirPrint mode for almost any printer, which is very handy feature.

Comment: How exactly does this enable scheduling of print jobs?